# import js functions to module.exports in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a `module.exports` file where I define a set of functions.
Typically the functions I place in there are queries to a mongodb database where I perform several actions in the records asynchronously.

Besides this, I have a helpers file that contains functions that are used accross several pieces of my code from different modules.

I want to be able to use these helper functions inside my `module.exports`:´

```
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {

    process: function(callback){

        var cursor = Col1.find().lean().cursor();
        cursor.on('data', function(doc) {

            console.log(helpers.function1(doc));
        });
        cursor.on('close', function() {
          // Called when done
          callback();
        });
    }
};
```

I am getting the following error for the line `console.log(helpers.function1(doc));` :

> TypeError: helpers.function1 is not a function

**helpers.js**:

```
function function1(record){
    return '';
};
```

Comment: `var helpers = ('./helpers');`??

Comment: Separately: If `helpers.js` is as shown, it doesn't export *anything*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder typo in my code i use require.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**: You need to export your function1 in helpers.js add :

```
module.exports = {function1};
```

And also replace

```
var helpers = ('./helpers');
```

To

```
var helpers = require('./helpers');
```

Comment: To be used the way the OP uses it, it would be `module.exports.function1 = function1;`, not `module.exports = function1;`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yours is the right answer post it and i'll accept it thanks.